# Flutter Windows option disabled in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, flutter-desktop

Windows option is disabled while creating a new Flutter project in IntelliJ IDEA. I've upgraded my Flutter to Flutter 2 stable channel but getting Windows option disabled whereas I've also installed Visual Studio 2019 in my PC.

[image]

Here's my Flutter doctor results

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run the following commands

flutter config --enable-windows-desktop

flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-windows-uwp-desktop

flutter doctor

Then as per the instruction of the above command, you may have to install required tools like Visual Studio...

Finally in IntelliJ

New Project -> Select Flutter -> Select SDK Location, Click Next

(Now if you still see Windows is disabled)

Press Back & Then press next... Now, I am seeing it can be enabled.

Even after that if you are not seeing, allow the project to finish without selecting the windows (or try to select web)

Then provide the following command on the project root directory
flutter create --platforms=windows